# Powering a small pump from a Raspberry Pico microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, charge-pump

I'm trying to power a small 5 V pump from a [Pico Raspberry](https://www.kubii.fr/cartes-raspberry-pi/3205-raspberry-pi-pico-3272496311589.html) board power PIN (Vsys) that also powers an [OLED display](https://www.kubii.fr/ecrans-supports/3423-module-d-affichage-oled-13-pouces-pour-raspberry-pi-pico-64-128-spii2c-5903351249775.html).

When the pump is activated it causes the microcontroler to reset. I think this is because of the pump's current demand, which is high. I would like to have your suggestions on how to solve this problem without using a second power source.

This is the circuit used for the pump:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Please find below the characteristics of the pump:

- Voltage: CC 3-5 V
- Operating current: 100-200 mA
- Load power: 0,4-1,5 W
- Water flow: 80-120 liter/h

Comment: What current does the pump require, and how much current can your power source provide?  You should connect the pump directly to the power source so the pump current does not flow through the pico or its supply wires.

Comment: I will update my post by adding the pump characteristics.

Comment: @PeterBennett, My main power supply is a 3.7V Lithium battery. I have already tried to power the pump directly from the source and I got the same result.

Comment: How much current does the pico require...(max)?

Comment: @RussellH The  current  consumption of pico is  93mA.  And The max current recommended in pin 3V3 is 300mA.